# What are those flight level values on an airway?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, icao-sarps, flight-level, spain

I have downloaded from [this link](https://aip.enaire.es/contenido_cartasInsigniaImpresas/ENR_Canarias_Superior_VIGOR.pdf) the chart of available airways over the Canary Islands. There, in some of the airways, it says

```
FL660
FL145
```

[image]

As far as I know, these two numbers are the maximum and minimum values of the [flight level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_level) which can be used while traversing said airway. However, I haven't found any online document which can be used as a source to verify if I am right or not. Can someone please indicate where I can read about chart interpretation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's an official chart from the [Spanish AIP](https://aip.enaire.es/AIP/AIP-en.html), so we can refer to ENR 3.3 for the ATS routes (airways):

> [image]

Taking the UM871 example, the FL 145 to FL 660 are the vertical limits, just like how an airspace has lateral and vertical boundaries, the same goes for airways.

Also if interested GEN 3.2 lists the standards followed in creating the charts, notes any differences from ICAO's standards, and also lists the manual.

Since that chart is an upper airspace chart, it only includes the vertical limits, but in a lower airspace chart, the smaller value can be the MEA (minimum en-route altitude) or the MOCA (minimum obstacle clearance altitude) according to ICAO's [specimen AIP](https://www.icao.int/airnavigation/information-management/Pages/SpecimenAIP.aspx) (icao.int).